# proof ideas for converging of nets under weak topoology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

If $X$ has the weak topology generated by a family $\mathcal{F}$ of functions, then a net $<x_{\alpha}>_{\alpha \in \Omega}$ converge to $x$ in $X$ if and only if $<f(x_\alpha)>$ converge to $f(x)$.

So at first glance, it seems like the proof should be fairly straightforward since all function in $\mathcal{F}$ is continuous under the weak topology by definition, then we functions are continuous if and only if the above condition holds for all net. But I want to ask if there is anything that I missed or if I am completely off the track in proving the question.

Please give some hints or a broad idea of proof, where I can try to fill in the details.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to specify a few bits of information about the functions involved for this to be correct. Even then, you've really only proved the forward implication. What you want to show is the following:

Let $X$ be a set and let $(Y,\tau)$ be a topological space. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of functions $f: X \to Y$ and assume that $X$ has the weak topology generated by $\mathcal{F}$. Then, a net $(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in \Omega}$ converges to $x$ in $X$ in the weak topology iff $f(x_{\alpha}) \to f(x)$ for every $f \in X$.

$\implies:$

Since each $f \in \mathcal{F}$ is continuous by definition, the result follows immediately from a standard characterization of continuity by net convergence.

$\impliedby:$

Let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$ in the weak topology. Due to the subbasis characterization of the weak topology, it is enough to assume that $U = f^{-1}(V)$, for some open set $V \subseteq Y$ and some $f \in \mathcal{F}$. Since $V$ is open around $f(x)$, $f(x_{\alpha})$ eventually lies in $V$. This immediately implies that $x_{\alpha} \in U$ eventually and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But I am still a bit confused about why we can take arbitrary topological space $Y$ instead of the product of $Y_\beta$, and each $f\in \mathcal{F}$ the coordinate maps that map $X$ to each $Y_\beta$

Comment: Could you formulate the exact statement that you are proposing is true? I can see where you're going with this but I just want to be entirely sure.